# Inverse of Polylogarithm

Tags: polylogarithms

I am considering the polylogarithm $Li_n(x)$
What is the inverse function for polylogarithm $Li_n(x)$, where n is any complex value?
Thanks,
Gevorg.

Comment: for $n=0$ or $n=1$ it's an elementary function, quite unlikely for arbitrary $n$.

Comment: Dear @Carlo Beenakker. Yes it is. i just met an issue when trying to solve some equation for arbitrary n, but seems this is very complex task.

Comment: The function is conformal when n>0 so an inverse does exist.  Does it have a name?